# Pass selected text to default search engine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome/FF Quantum extension, and I've run into a problem. This extension creates a floating toolbar via content script, when the user selects some text on the webpage.

The toolbar has an "Open" button. What I want to do is to open a new tab, and pass the selected text to it. If the selected text is a valid URL, it should be opened. If it's only arbitrary text, it should be passed to the **default** search engine of the browser. Just like when the user types into the addressbar.

So far I have a content and a background script. The content script reads the selected text and sends it to the background script with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`. In that script I've tried both the `chrome.tabs.create()` and the `window.open()` methods, but if the selection is only arbitrary text, the new tab loads with the URL of the extension itself, and attaches the text to the path part.

Is it even possible to do, or I have to use a search engine as a user setting of the extension, and build the query myself?

Comment: When using `chrome.tabs'create()` as a URL you can pass `"http://www.google.com/search?q=" + arbitraryText` in order to use Google for example which is the default browser and the most common one. I am not aware of any ways to get the default search engine but you can add an option in your extension to select the most popular ones and then simply change the hardcoded part of the URL parameter accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to this solution in my last paragraph. I could do this, but it would be much more elegant and convenient to find a way, which can be handled by the browser.